# How to add an attribute in a tag in XML file by command-line?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, files, sed, xml

I am trying to add field at the end of tag using sed script. Suppose I have a tag in XML file:

```
<book name="Sed tutorial" price="250"/>
```

Now I want to add field as `Book_Width="A"` after end of `<book/>` tag so that my tag becomes:

```
<book name="Sed tutorial" price="250" Book_Width="A"/>
```

I tried with `sed`:

```
sed '/<book "[^>]*>/ a Book_Width="A"'
```

but it gives:

```
<book name="Sed tutorial" price="250"/>
Book_Width="A"
```

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should not parse XML with `sed`; use an XML parser such as `xmlstarlet` instead. For your task it would be:

```
xmlstarlet ed -O --inplace --insert "/book" --type attr -n Book_Width -v A xml_file
```

The file content is then:

```
<book name="Sed tutorial" price="250" Book_Width="A"/>
```

- The `ed` means edit mode to edit the XML tree.
- `-O` omits the XML tag.
- We want to insert something with `--insert`.
- `"/book"` is the path where to insert.
- `--type attr`: it's an attribute we want to insert.
- The name `-n` of the attribute.
- The value `-v`.

Comment: can I update xml_file rather printing its output

Comment: @krishna Yes with `--inplace` I added it to my answer

Comment: If Book_Width="A" already present in XML file then how can we skip that tag

Answer (score 5):

in `sed` "a" appends a pattern IN A NEW LINE.

what you want to do is replace (`s`ubstitute). Let's use a colon as separator for clarity:

```
sed 's:\(<book.*\)\(/>\):\1 Book_Width="A"\2:'
```

anything in `\( .. \)` is a pattern memorized by the order of appearance and recalled by `\indexnumber` , e.g. `\1` will reproduce the first pattern saved.

So we are memorizing `<book name="Sed tutorial" price="250"` as pattern 1 and `/>` as pattern 2 and just insert `Book_Width="A"` in the middle.

```
echo '<book name="Sed tutorial" price="250"/>' | sed 's:\(<book.*\)\(/>\):\1 Book_Width="A"\2:'
<book name="Sed tutorial" price="250" Book_Width="A"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that your XML file is literally just a single line with a `book` node, as shown in the question, you may add a `Book_Width` attribute to that `book` node using `xq` (part of `yq` from https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/) like so:

```
$ xq -x '.book."@Book_Width" |= "A"' file.xml
<book name="Sed tutorial" price="250" Book_Width="A"></book>
```

If you have data that you'd like to insert as the attribute's value:

```
$ myvariable='20 cm'
$ xq -x --arg val "$myvariable" '.book."@Book_Width" |= $val' file.xml
<book name="Sed tutorial" price="250" Book_Width="20 cm"></book>
```

Answer (score 1):

With `awk` you can do something like this:

Supposing the line is in file *file1.xml* then:

```
awk -F '/' '{print $1,"Book_Width=\"A\"",FS,$2}' file1.xml
```

Comment: This is not checking that the tag is "book"

Comment: In general a solution using sed or awk is only going to work on a subset of XML; if it works on the subset of XML that you apply it to, then that's fine. Just be aware that it will break as soon as it gets unexpected input; and if you put it into production, then we will see a slew of StackOverflow questions from people who want to know how to generate your chosen (proprietary and probably undocumented) subset of XML. Don't laugh - it happens all the time.

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be to use `sed` and not use any external packages or commands.

```bash
echo '<book name="Sed tutorial" price="250"/>' |
sed 's/<book /& Book_Width="A"/'
```

Output:

```
<book Book_Width="A" name="Sed tutorial" price="250"/>
```

If you have a file.

```
sed 's/<book /& Book_Width="A"/' ${FILE_NAME}
```

or if you want to replace inplace

```
sed -i 's/<book /& Book_Width="A"/' ${FILE_NAME}
```

`&`: This symbol is a special character in sed that represents the entire matched string, i.e., <book(space). We use it here in the replacement pattern to include the original <book tag in the modified text.

Comment: It is generaly a bad practiec to use awk/sed/perl to edit XML files. What would happen if there is a `bookmark` tag ?

Comment: Best solution would be _not_ to use `sed` but instead to use an XML-aware parser

Comment: How about when you have an environment where you are allowed to use any 3rd party software?

Comment: Don't accept a job if you are forced to do bad practice. Move on next inc that care modern and robust coding.